# Is it able to view protected accounts using twitter api?

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm using Python to get texts of tweets from twitter using `tweepy` and is it possible to get ID and password from user, pass it to twitter api, and access to the tweets and get json data.

I read "User timelines belonging to protected users may only be requested when the authenticated user either “owns” the timeline or is an approved follower of the owner." but not sure whether it means the programmer must be accessible to the protected account or the api can access to protected account by receiving ID and password.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

The User Credentials is what determines permissions. With OAuth a user gives your app permission to act on their behalf.